# memoir class changes typesize

Tags: memoir

I'm using the `memoir` document class to typeset a document. This is my first time with `memoir`. I've read the documentation carefully and can't find an answer to the problem described below.

The command

`\documentclass[executivepaper,12pt,onecolumn,openany]{memoir}`

produces a document with 12pt type.

The following command without `executive paper`

`\documentclass[12pt,onecolumn,openany]{memoir}`

typesets a document with 10pt type.

Why does the type size change?

I'll be grateful for suggestions.

Comment: How are you determining fontsize? These produce identical font sizes for me: `HHNMVP+CMR12` with `pdflatex` and `CJGEDQ+LMRoman12-Regular` with LuaLaTeX, as reported by `pdffonts` and using an up-to-date TeX Live.

Answer (score 1):

It is an "optical" illusion created by the pdf viewer that expands the smaller page. If you use an external viewer, set the windows to a fixed width to see what happens, or the internal viewer at 100% in both cases.

You can output the font size using the internal LaTeX command `\f@size`. Here I set a length `\myfontsize` to this value
and used `\the\myfontsize` to print its value in the document.

The text area is the same in both cases, only the margins changed.

Executive paper

[image: ex]

Default paper size

[image: de]

This is `letter.tex`

```
\documentclass[12pt,onecolumn,openany]{memoir}

\newlength{\myfontsize}
\makeatletter
\setlength{\myfontsize}{\f@size pt}
\makeatother

\usepackage{showframe} % ONLY to show the margins

\begin{document}
    
Font size = \the\myfontsize 

paper size default 8.5 x 11 in
    
As any dedicated reader can clearly see, the Ideal of practical reason is
a representation of, as far as I know, the things in themselves; as I have
shown elsewhere, the phenomena should only be used as a canon for our
understanding.

Font size = \the\myfontsize

\end{document}
```

This is `executive.tex`

```
\documentclass[executivepaper,12pt,onecolumn,openany]{memoir}


\newlength{\myfontsize}
\makeatletter
\setlength{\myfontsize}{\f@size pt}
\makeatother

\usepackage{showframe} % ONLY to show the margins

\begin{document}
    
Font size = \the\myfontsize 

paper size executive 7.25 x 10.5 in
    
As any dedicated reader can clearly see, the Ideal of practical reason is
a representation of, as far as I know, the things in themselves; as I have
shown elsewhere, the phenomena should only be used as a canon for our
understanding.

Font size = \the\myfontsize

\end{document}
```